# Passing three parameter in map shows error

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to pass three parameters in map in C++.  It shows error while using insert function.  Is there any alternate method for this?  I want to make pair of ((integer integer) string)

```
int main()
{
    map < map <int, int>, char[50] >  Code;

    int TestCases,Queries,a,b;
    char Name[50];
    scanf("%d",&TestCases);

    for (int i = 0; i < TestCases; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %s",&a,&b,Name);
        Code.insert(make_pair(make_pair(a,b),Name[50]));// Error    Line 
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> C2664: 'void std::_Tree`<`std::_Tmap_traits`<`_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false`>>`::insert(std::initializer_list<const _Kty,_Ty`>>`)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair`<`std::pair`<`int,int`>`,char`>`' to 'std::pair`<`const _Kty,_Ty`>`

Comment: It's really strange have and std::map as the key of any other container and probably the performance would be affected, this is the intended goal.

Comment: That is not the complete error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the usage, it looks like you really want the key to be a pair of ints, not a map of int to int, like so:

```
std::map< std::pair<int,int>, char[50] > Code;
```

Furthermore, if you are storing a string in a map, it's preferable to use the C++ string class instead of a C char array.

```
std::map< std::pair<int,int>, std::string > Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the 'Name' pointer, not an index to array index [50].

```
Code.insert(make_pair(make_pair(a,b),Name));
```

Also may have to change your map declaration to:

```
map < map <int, int>, char* >  Code;
```

But I am not positive about that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change

   ```
   map < map <int, int>, char[50] > Code;
   ```

   to

   ```
   map <pair <int,int>, string > Code;
   ```

   This will associate one single pair of `int`'s with each `string`, which is what I assume you want, rather than associating an entire `map` with only one pair in it with each `string`, which would be cumbersome and a waste.
2. Change all of your `char[50]`'s to `string`'s. They will serve you much better.
3. Change line #11 (the make_pair line) to:

   ```
   Code.insert(pair<pair<int,int>,string>(pair<int,int>(a,b),Name));
   ```

   This will properly fill up `Code` as you want it to.

And also, I might suggest using `cout` and `cin`, rather than `scanf`, which is a C function. they're also much more forgiving.